# Need to fit images in one page in PDF exported using wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wicked-pdf

I am using wicked_pdf to generate PDF (landscape mode) in my Rails(3.0) application. Everything is working just fine with a small glitch. I have a looping of dynamic sized data (say comments and images) which are sequentially arranged.The images have a frame into which they are placed. I need to move the framed image to next page if it does not fit in the space on the current page. Currently what is happening is,the end part of the frame moves to the next page if doesn't fit.

Comment: @FreeSprint could please provide some visual information into it may then we can help

Answer (score 1):

I use the this css style to controll auot page break:

```
img.auto-page-break { 
    page-break-before: auto;  
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could try wrapping a div around your content and the following in your CSS.

```
div.page {
  width: 180mm;
  height: 277mm;
  overflow: hidden;
  page-break-after: auto;
}
```